# Regex to find dates before a certain year

Tags: c#, regex, string

So i have a string that has different dates and I want to only find dates on or before 1998. The format in the string is dd-mm-yyyy. This is what I have so far

```
Regex test = new Regex(@".*\d\d-\d\d-(18|19)\d\d");
```

I just don't know how can I make it so that it only finds dates on or before 1998.

Comment: including 3 digit years? or 1000-1999 OK?

Comment: Have you tried using Datetime?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: @weston 1000 to 1998 is okay. sorry I meant 1998 not 1999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Years 1000 to 1999 can be matched with `1\d\d\d`

Years 1000 to 1998 can be matched with `(1[0-8][0-9]{2}|19[0-8][0-9]|199[0-8])`

No I can't write them out that quick I used: http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

Personally, I might be tempted to do in two steps, find ones in likely range (1000-1999) then actually parse them and check the actual date, particularly if your requirements get any more complex.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, just click the upvote. And tick if you can, you may need to come back later to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This one is a little more in depth, will also constrain months to 1-12, and days 1-31, will allow 01-09 for both, and goes up to 12-31-1998

```
@"(?<!\d)(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])-(?:[0-2]?[1-9]|3[0-1])-1\d(?:\d[0-8]|[0-8]\d)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jmargolisvt that it seems this would be best solved with the Datetime object. But, if there's some reason you must use regex ...

You can use @weston's original idea to restrict from 1000 to 1999:
`.*\d{2}-\d{2}-1\d{3}`

But add a negative-lookahead to eliminate 1999 explicitly:
`.*\d{2}-\d{2}-(?!1999)1\d{3}`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest combining *regular expressions* and *Linq*:

- `Regex` extracts matches that *can* be date
- *Linq* ensures (via `DateTime.TryParseExact`) that they are date and filter out years

Implementation

```
  // Expected date; invalid date; date out the range
  string source = "20-10-1950 29-02-1955 23-02-2097";

  var result = Regex
    .Matches(source, "[0-3][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]{3}")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => {
      DateTime dt;
      bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Value, 
        "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt);

      return new {
        valid = valid,
        value = dt,
      };
    })
    .Where(item => item.valid && item.value.Year <= 1998)
    .Select(item => item.value);

  // 20.10.1950 12:00:00 
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: Hmm, the `valid` stuff sure uglies it up. How about a method such that: `.SelectMany(match => TryParseDate(match))` And then `TryParseDate` returns one or zero items.

Comment: @weston: it's a reasonable way, e.g. if  `TryParseDate` returns `DateTime?` (i.e. either parsed date or `null`); the downside of approach is that one has to implement `DateTime? TryParseDate(string value)` method

Comment: Well for my suggestion to succeed, I think `TryParseDate` needs to return an enumerable, either empty, or one element. (Note the `SelectMany`)

Comment: It'll make the Linq shorter, but, IMHO, `IEnumerable<TDateTime> TryParseDate(string value)` signature will be very *confusing* one (when parsing we expect to obtain a single value, and here we have a collection)

Comment: I agree, it moves the ugly, and possibly confuses things. Perhaps the nullable route (`DateTime?`) would make it more fluent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example that validates the date a little bit, not allowing month numbers or day numbers that can't exist.

`(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(?:1\d\d[0-8])`

https://regex101.com/r/Ml5WTK/1

Comment: Thank for that website it is a great tool to have!